# My button size changes when I change the label text in my panel when using GridBagLayout

Tags: java, button, label, gridbaglayout

I have a simple JFrame class and in that class I have a problem with GridBagLayout that whenever I change the label text, the buttons below that adapt to the same size of the label. I want it so that buttons don't change their size whenever label text changes. Here is the code where I create the main panel:

```
public void createView( JFrame frame)
{   
  panel = new JPanel( new GridBagLayout() );

  GridBagConstraints c;
  c = new GridBagConstraints();
  c.gridx = 2;
  c.gridy = 0;      

  label = new JLabel( "  Guesses: " + guesses);
  c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
  c.gridwidth = 1;
  panel.add( label, c);

  for ( int i = 0; i < 25; i++ )
  {

     c.gridx++;

     if ( i % 5 == 0 )
     {
        c.gridy++;
        c.gridx = 0;
     }

     button = new JButton( "BOX " + ( i + 1 ) );
     button.addActionListener( new Action() );
     panel.add( button, c);
  }

  panel.setBackground( Color.YELLOW);
  frame.add( panel);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#setMaximumSize(java.awt.Dimension)

setMaximumSize(Dimension) call this for the button and set your constant size :)

Comment: It doesn't work unfortunely, I did some research on the method and some people said that it is bugged.